# how do i kill an entire process after its finished from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, autohotkey, autoit

I'm looking to kill an entire process after it finsihes. The problem I have is, I don't know how long the process may take. It may take 2 minutes or it may take 1.5 hours to complete. After it completes, it pops up two windows which I have to click "OK" to. As I want to automate the process I want to completely kill the process so it performs the next step in the .bat file.

This is what I've got so far in the .bat file below. AutoIT and AHK solutions also happily accepted. PLEASE NOTE*** The main application window and the popup windows have the same name which is "AutoMe".

```
@echo off
:: this is the long running process
am -a arobot
:: I was hoping this would kill the process but it just gets stuck with a
:: messagebox
taskkill /F /IM am.exe
:: Next step to perform
sqlldr XXXXXX
pause
```

Comment: not really going to work. since that task is alive and blocking while it pops up those "ok" prompts, your taskkill will never get reached. you'd have to run it as a separate job, and somehow monitor it for those popups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is two AutoIt solutions.

If you don't need to click the two okay buttons before your kill the process.

```
While 1
    Sleep(250)
    If WinExists("Title of the window with the OK button") Then ExitLoop
WEnd

;Close process. Make sure that am.exe is the process name.
ProcessClose("am.exe")
```

If you  need to click the two okay buttons before your kill the process.

```
While 1
    Sleep(250)
    If WinExists("Title of the window with the OK button") Then ExitLoop
WEnd

$hWnd = WinGetHandle("Title of the window with the OK button")
WinActivate($hWnd)
WinWaitActive($hWnd)
ControlClick("My Window", "", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:OK; INSTANCE:1]") ;<<<check to make sure you have the right button control

WinWait("title of second window")
$hWnd = WinGetHandle("title of second window")
WinActivate($hWnd)
WinWaitActive($hWnd)
ControlClick("My Window", "", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:OK; INSTANCE:1]") ;<<<check to make sure you have the right button control

;Close process. Make sure that am.exe is the process name.
ProcessClose("am.exe")
```

When the pop upwindow has the same name as the main window you can look for the ok button control or any other control in that window instead of the window title.

```
While 1
    Sleep(250)
    If ControlCommand("win title", "", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:OK; INSTANCE:1]", "IsVisible", "") = 1 Then ExitLoop
WEnd
```

Another alternative is checking for the window handle. When you use WinGetHandle and there is two windows with the same name it will get the handle of the most recently active window. In your case you can use this feature to see when the popup window comes up.

```
$hWnd = WinGetHandle("Window title")

While 1
    Sleep(250)
    If $hWnd <> WinGetHandle("Window title") Then ExitLoop
WEnd
```

You can use the [AutoIt Window Information Tool](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm) to find the controls and window titles.

Answer (score 0):

Start the process in background and wait for a window with the specified title `Some Window Title`:

```dos
@echo off
start "" /b am -a arobot
:wait
    timeout 1 >nul
    for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('
        tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Some Window Title" /fo list ^| find "PID:"
    ') do (
        taskkill /f /pid %%a
        goto next
    )
    goto wait

:next
sqlldr XXXXXX
pause
```

Comment: Just tried it and it seems the taskkill kills the whole process before it even gets started. it just skips over the am -a arobot and goes onto the next task

Comment: Well you didn't tell that program always displays a window and its title doesn't change so of course it's killed. I guess to stay with batch language limits you'll need a utility like [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) (the CLI version `nircmdc`).